# On limits of positive linear functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking for pointers to the literature on questions of the following kind. ($Y$ and $\Omega$ might be open subsets of some Euclidean space, but I am interested in the kind of conditions that need to be imposed on all spaces in order to get a result of the indicated type.)

Let $E$ be a space of functions $e:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ and let $F$ be a space of functions $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$. With respect to pointwise ordering, let $\mu$ be a positive linear functional on $F$ and let $\lambda:E\to F$ be a positive linear mapping.

Under which natural conditions is there a function $y:\mathbb{R}\times\Omega\to Y$ (depending on $\mu$ and $\lambda$) such that the functions $e_t\in F$ defined for $e\in E$ by
$$ e_t(\omega):=e(y(t,\omega))$$
satisfy
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \mu(e_t)=\mu(\lambda(e))$$
for all $e\in E$? (The intuition behind this condition is that y ''approximates'' $\lambda$ in a loose sense, and the families $e_t$ approximate the $\lambda(e)$ in a kind of uniform way.)

How nice can $y$ be chosen?

Comment: Could use specify what $Y$ and $\Omega$ are? Also, may I suggest to denote the real field in the question by the (somewhat more common, I believe) notation $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $R$? This would make it a bit easier (at least for me) to distinguish the roles of the various objects.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I understand correctly that you would like the limit equality to be true for all $\mu$ and all $e$ (but for a function $y$ that does not depend on $\mu$ and $e$)?

Comment: @JochenGlueck: No. $y$ depends on the arbitrary $\mu$ and $\lambda$ but not on $e$. This should have been deducible already from the old formulation but I added it now explicitly.

Comment: Hmm, than I'm a bit confused: if $y$ is allowed to depend on $\mu$, I don't quite understand the role of the operator $\lambda$. One could instead simply start with two positive functionals $\mu, \tilde \mu$ on $F$ and ask whether there is a function $y$ such that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \mu(e_t) = \tilde \mu(e)$ holds for all $e$, right? (Since it is not relevant for the question how one obtains $\tilde \mu$ from $\mu$).

Comment: (By the way, sorry for my numerous requests for clarification; I find the question very interesting, but would like to make sure that I'm really thinking about the same question as you intended.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck: The intuition behind my question is that $y$ somehow approximates $\lambda$, and the families $e_t$ approximate the $\lambda(e)$ in a kind of uniform way.  I believe that it should be essentially always possible to find $y$ given this condition (possibly with restrictions on the function spaces considered). With your formulation, one would probably have to posit some nontrivial relation between $\mu$ and $\widetilde \mu$.